# Show that $|f(x,y)| \leq 3x^2$, $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ is differentiable in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

I am stuck on a question:

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function with the property \begin{equation} |f(x,y)| \leq 3x^2, \quad (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}\end{equation}
Prove that $f$ is differentiable in $(0,1)$.

I have already shown that $f(0,1) = f_x(0,1) = f_y(0,1) = 0$, but I do not know how to go from there. Proving continuity of $f_x$, $f_y$ does the trick, but I would not know how to. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition you have to show that there exists $(p,q)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$
\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{f(h, 1+k) - f(0,1) - p h - q k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} = 0.
$$
You have already shown that the "candidate" $(p,q)$ is $(0,0)$ (the gradient of $f$ at $(0,1)$).

Using the given estimate you thus have $f(0,1) = 0$ and
$$
\left|
\frac{f(h, 1+k) - f(0,1) - p h - q k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}
\right|
=
\frac{|f(h, 1+k)|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}
\leq \frac{3h^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \leq 3 |h|,
$$
hence the l.h.s. goes to $0$ when $(h,k) \to (0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.